# Multiple databases or namespace in Hbase

Tags: hbase

Is there a way to setup Hbase so we can create multiples databases inside the same cluster ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to refresh topic: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#namespace

5.3.1. Namespace management
A namespace can be created, removed or altered. Namespace membership is determined during table creation by specifying a fully-qualified table name of the form:

:
Example 5.1. Examples

```
#Create a namespace
create_namespace 'my_ns'

#create my_table in my_ns namespace
create 'my_ns:my_table', 'fam'

#drop namespace
drop_namespace 'my_ns'

#alter namespace
alter_namespace 'my_ns', {METHOD => 'set', 'PROPERTY_NAME' => 'PROPERTY_VALUE'}
```

Answer (score 4):

No there's none. However, you can use prefixes for table names to separate a set of tables from another set.

I didn't test ACLs before, but I think you can use them in recent versions of hbase > 0.92 to allow access to some tables and prevent access to others per user.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces support is coming in the 0.96.0 release.  More and more features will be built in as time passes.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8015