# How to create database in Hbase?

Tags: hbase

For example, in postgres, I can create two different database A, B and I can create tables in both A and B. But when I use java api with Hbase it seems that I can only create table, how can I create a database in Hbase?

Comment: have you check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054230/multiple-databases-or-namespace-in-hbase
so by default, the whole space in hbase belong to one default "database", you can't define any other one..

Answer (score 0):

HBase 0.96 [added the notion of namespaces](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8015) which is similar to the concept you're looking for. You can use the [HBaseAdmin](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#createNamespace%28org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NamespaceDescriptor%29) class to create namespaces and then create tables within them